# Cheapest FPGA PCIe board for Software Acceleration

Tags: fpga, vhdl, verilog, board, pcie

This question is somewhat related to an earlier question: [Cheapest FPGA's](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/2641/cheapest-fpgas).

I have been searching for a cheap FPGA board with PCI express 2.0 or 3.x support. Such boards can be plugged in one of the compatible PCIe slot on a motherboard, and can be programmed using either HDL entry or OpenCL or C/C++ based HLS tools. In order to facilitate data transfer between CPU DDR and FPGA DDR memory, the board comes with programmable DMA controllers.

There is a company which sells such boards(Nallatech), but the starting board prices are just too high (> 5000 USD). Then there are FPGA PCIe boards sold by [Xilinx](http://www.fpgadeveloper.com/2014/03/comparison-of-7-series-fpga-boards-for-pcie.html) and [Altera](http://www.terasic.com.tw/cgi-bin/page/archive.pl?Language=English&CategoryNo=165&No=843) with minimum 1300 USD price. But all these are still too expensive for me. **Can someone recommend a cheaper FPGA board from Xilinx/Altera with a PCIe 2.0 or 3.x support ?**.

Comment: Shopping questions are off topic on ee.se. But either way, cheap and PCIe don't go together. You can get Stratix IV boards for $4000 or so.

Comment: 1) PCIe transceivers are only embedded in mid-range and high-end FPGAs. 2) These FPGAs need a complex power supply and wiring, which need expensiv PCBs. 3) Only big FPGAs are attractive for accelerator usage and HLS purposes. 4) because you want to use high-level approches, you'll need a set of IP cores (PCIe, DMA, DDR RAM vontroller, ...) these cores are expensive and are only shipped with high-end boards. 5) Nallatech boards for 5000 USD are cheap compared to other boards :).

Comment: The FPGA itself is the majority of the cost of the board. Take one of those boards, and search on the FPGA part number alone.

Comment: @Alex - true dat ... there was a time when the price on the Xilinx boards (ML506,7) I mentioned was less than the one-off price quoted by distributors for the FPGA... may still be true for the boards above.

Comment: PicoEVB is the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look around for an old ML506 or ML507 from Xilinx, but really $1300 is a reasonable price for these boards.

There is one other option I can think of: the [Raggedstone 2](http://www.enterpoint.co.uk/products/spartan-6-development-boards/raggedstone-2/) from Enterpoint, at prices from about [$400 upwards](http://www.enterpoint.co.uk/shop/en/11-raggedston2.html) according to the FPGA (Spartan-6, different sizes). They have a range of other options with up to 25 FPGAs, but probably outside your price range

Comment: Those links are down in the future, but I can suggest [numato.com](https://numato.com/product/galatea-pci-express-spartan-6-fpga-development-board/) for a low cost PCIe FPGA card ($380 to $647) in the present. The low end one is pretty strong, you have quite a bit of resources. I have a device with the same FPGA from them.